# Laravel DI value is empty

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, routes

This one works

```
     public function show($id)
    {
        $request = ClientRequest::find($id);
        return view('show', compact('request'));
    }
```

This one does not work!!
`dd($request)` indicates null atrributes

```
    public function show(ClientRequest $request)
    {
        return view('show', compact('request'));
    }
```

This is my route

```
Auth::routes();

Route::resource('pioneer', RequestController::class);
```

Model

```
class ClientRequest extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Anyone knows where the problem is ? I've googled, but still cannot figure out.

Comment: can you update your route as well?

Comment: With route model binding, the URL segment and function parameter must match. Therefore ensure that the segment in your route definition is called `{request}` and not something else.

Comment: Make sure the route variable is exact the same as the one in your show method: `$request`

Comment: I use ```Route::resource()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, with [`route model binding`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) the URL segment and function parameter name must match.

Your URL segment is `pioneer` as defined by your `Resource` route definition, therefore you need to use `pioneer` as your function parameter name.

```
public function show(ClientRequest $pioneer)
{
    return view('show', compact('pioneer'));
}
```

Comment: Appreciate!! it works now!!! thanks!!